# Mocking chained methods

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

(I use Jest for testing)
For example, I have this function:

```
const find = () => {
    return {
        where: () => {
            in: () => {}
        }
    };
};
```

and I call that in different place:

```
find('me').where('id').in(['123']);
```

How to mock and test calls in find(), where() and in()?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dirt simple mock interface:

```js
const find = (findData) => {
    const data = {
      find: findData
    };
    const self = {
      where: (whereData) => {
        data.where = whereData;
        return self;
      },
      in: (inData) => {
        data.in = inData;
        return self;
      },
      data
    };
    
    return self;
};

const res = find('me').where('id').in(['123']);

console.log(res.data);
```

Comment: I didn't see any relation with jest.js